# Exception during IR lowering when adding a single file to the module

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have been reading some threads with the same name but none is applicable to my issue here
I have four files in a module called post:

```
class PostListConverter @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext val context: Context
) {
    fun convert(postListResult: Result<GetPostsWithUsersWithInteractionUseCase.Response>): UiState<PostListModel>{
        return when(postListResult) {
            is Result.Error ->
                UiState.Error(postListResult.exception.localizedMessage.orEmpty())
            is Result.Success -> {
                UiState.Success(
                    PostListModel(
                        headerText = context.getString(
                            R.string.total_click_count,
                            postListResult.data.interaction.totalClicks
                        ),
                        items = postListResult.data.posts.map {
                            PostListItemModel(
                                it.post.id,
                                it.user.id,
                                context.getString(R.string.author, it.user.name),
                                context.getString(R.string.title, it.post.title)
                            )
                        }
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the second file

```
    data class PostListItemModel(
    val id: Long,
    val userId: Long,
    val authorName: String,
    val title: String
)

data class PostListModel(
    val headerText: String = "",
    val items: List<PostListItemModel> = listOf()
)
```

This is the third file

```
    @HiltViewModel
class PostListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val useCase: GetPostsWithUsersWithInteractionUseCase,
    private val converter: PostListConverter
): ViewModel(){
    private val _postListFlow = MutableStateFlow<UiState<PostListModel>>(UiState.Loading)
    val postListFlow = _postListFlow.asStateFlow()

    fun loadPosts(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            useCase.execute(GetPostsWithUsersWithInteractionUseCase.Request)
                .map {
                    converter.convert(it)
                }.collect{
                    _postListFlow.value = it
                }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the fourth file for the UI:

```
    sealed class UiState<out T: Any>{
    object Loading: UiState<Nothing>()
    data class Error< T:Any>(val errorMessage: String): UiState<T>()
    data class Success< T: Any>(val data: T): UiState<T>()
}
```

As they are in the same module I could run Make on them and no errors whatsoever flagged.
But when I add the following file, this error appears `org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering`

```
@Composable
fun PostListScreen(
    viewModel: PostListViewModel
) {
    viewModel.loadPosts()
    viewModel.postListFlow.collectAsState().value.let { state ->
        when (state) {
            is UiState.Loading -> {
                Loading()
            }
            is UiState.Error -> {
                Error(state.errorMessage)
            }
            is UiState.Success -> {
                PostList(state.data)
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun PostList(
    postListModel: PostListModel
) {
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
        item(postListModel.headerText) {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
                Text(text = postListModel.headerText)
            }
        }
        items(postListModel.items) { item ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
            ) {
                Text(text = item.authorName)
                Text(text = item.title)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Error(errorMessage: String) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom
    ) {
        Snackbar {
            Text(text = errorMessage)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Loading() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        CircularProgressIndicator()
    }
}
```

I am running android studio giraffe and here are the dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.48")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")
    //coroutines
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.1")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")

    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.2")

    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.6.0")
    implementation(project(path = ":domain"))


    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material")

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```